# how to make virtualenv with another interpreter?

Tags: python, virtualenv, interpreter, pythonpath

```
juldou@juldou-machine:~/Programovanie/Python/Projects/project_sql$ /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv project_sql
```

Output of the command above:

```
Using base prefix '/home/juldou/anaconda3'
New python executable in /home/juldou/Programovanie/Python/Projects/project_sql/project_sql/bin/python
/home/juldou/Programovanie/Python/Projects/project_sql/project_sql/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: The executable /home/juldou/Programovanie/Python/Projects/project_sql/project_sql/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home/juldou/Programovanie/Python/Projects/project_sql' (should be '/home/juldou/Programovanie/Python/Projects/project_sql/project_sql')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I want to use my python3.4 interpeter. How to make virtualenv with this interpreter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use different Python version with virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

First install `virtualenv`,
then

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

Now you have a venv with python3 interpreter